# HTML - Index html unable to access another html file in another folder

Tags: html, dom

I have my project folder and in my project folder I have a client and server folder. In the client folder I have my main `index.html` file. I created another html file called `products.html` and access that through index.html successfully like this `<a href="/products.html></a>`
However, later I decided to create a html folder and store all my html files in there. When I stored my `products.html` file in the html folder and accessed it through `index.html` like this `<a href="./html/product_categories/products.html"></a>` it doesnt work and instead I am getting a 404 error.

Why is the `index.html` file able to access the `products.html` file when they both are in the same folder but not when they are in separate folders?

```
***FOLDER STRUCTURE THAT WORKED***
project_name folder--> client folder--> index.html file & products.html
```

```
***FOLDER STRUCTURE THAT DIDNT WORK***
project_name folder --> client folder--> html folder --> product_categories --> products.html file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your folder structure looks something like this:

```
.
└── html
    ├── index.html
    └── product_categories
        └── products.html
```

This would be the correct way to reference `products.html` from your `index.html` file: `<a href="product_categories/products.html"></a>`

Comment: I see. the ```index.html``` file also has a script tag that refers to a javascript folder. I did it your way and now it cant read the script file. ```<script src="../javascript/init.js"></script>```

Comment: Can you confirm what your project's file structure looks like? I can only assume that the `javascript` folder isn't one level up relative from where your `index.html` file is.

Comment: So my javascript folder is outside my html folder. the index.html file is one level up. So in other words, the index.html only needs to exit the html folder and then enter the javascript folder where the javascript file resides.